# averagePair problem using multiple pointers as a solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pointers, average

I'm trying to solve the following problem :

[image]

What I've come up with so far:

```
function averagePair(arr,tar){

    if (arr.length < 2){
        return false
    }

    let x = 0

    for (var y = 1; y < arr.length; y++){
        if ((arr[x] + arr[y]) / 2 == tar){
            return true
        }
        else {
            x++;
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I know this solution isn't correct, can someone explain why? It works for some cases but not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution with `O(1)` additional space complexity and `O(n)` time complexity.

Since an array is sorted, it makes sense to have two indices: one going from begin to end (say `y`), another from end to begin of an array (say `x`).

Here's the code:

```js
function averagePair(arr,tar){
    
    // That's now included in for-loop condition
    // if (arr.length < 2) {
    //     return false;
    // }

    let x = arr.length - 1;

    for (var y = 0; y < x; y++) {

        // Division may lose precision, so it's better to compare
        //   arr[x] + arr[y] > 2*tar
        // than
        //   (arr[x] + arr[y]) / 2 > tar

        while (y < x && arr[x] + arr[y] > 2*tar) {
            x--;
        }
        if (x != y && arr[x] + arr[y] == 2*tar) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's kinda two-pointers technique: we'll decrease `x` until `a[x] + a[y] > 2*tar` for current loop iteration because we need to find the closest match. At the next for-loop iteration `a[y]` is greater or equal than the previous one, so it makes no sense to check if `a[z] + a[y] == 2*tar` for any `z > x`. We'll do this until indices aren't equal, which means there's no match.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! what exactly do you mean that division will lose precision?

Comment: @sofiat123 in this particular case division by two shouldn't cause any problems, but generally if you can it's better to avoid floating point calculations (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for example)

Answer (score 1):

You're only comparing adjacent elements, eg `[0]` vs `[1]`, and `[1]` vs `[2]`. You also need to compare `[0]` vs `[2]` and so on. The simplest tweak would be to use a nested loop:

```
for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
    if (x !== y) {
      // test arr[x] against arr[y]
```

But it'd be more elegant and less computationally complex (`O(n)` instead of `O(n ^ 2)`) to use a Set to keep track of what's been found so far:

```
const nums = new Set();
for (const num of arr) {
  if (nums.has(tar - num)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    nums.add(num);
  }
}
```

```js
function averagePair(arr,tar){
  const nums = new Set();
  for (const num of arr) {
    if (nums.has(tar - num)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      nums.add(num);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(averagePair([-2, 3, 2], 0));
console.log(averagePair([-2, 3, 3], 0));
```

Comment: I see - any ideas how to go about it without a nested loop. The question requires O(N) time complexity

Comment: Use a Set instead.